# Program Code finished with exit status 124

Tags: c

I'm trying to compute a function  using C program but getting an error. Code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double VOLT_DIV(double t, double b);

int main()
{
    double formula, VBAT_CONVERT, SCALER, VCC;
    SCALER = 100.00;
    VCC = 3.30;
    formula = VOLT_DIV(30.02, 4.72);
    VBAT_CONVERT = ((formula)*(VCC)*(SCALER));
    return VBAT_CONVERT;

}

double VOLT_DIV(double t, double b)
{
    double c;
    c = (((t) + (b))/b);
    return c;
}
```

I've modified type specifiers and format specifiers also added some headers after restarting the IDE i'm using. But no luck so far

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Hint: It is not printing anything.

Comment: You are returning VBAT_CONVERT which is 124, hence your return value. Did you mean to print it instead?

Comment: What format specifiers are you talking about? There are none.

Comment: Statements such as "it's not working" or "getting an error" [are not sufficient descriptions of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please elaborate, for example by specifying the desired output and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you return from `main` is the exit status of the program. In this case, the result of the calculation. Anything other than a value of `0` as an exit status is by convention considered an error. I suppose you want to print the result instead, so use

```
printf("%f", VBAT_CONVERT);
return 0;
```

Comment: Re “Anything other than `0` as an exit status is considered an error”: That is up to the system; it is not required by the C standard. (Also, note that `0` means the character “0” in source code. The value zero may be obtained in other ways and returned by `main` and still serves as a success exit status. To refer to the value zero rather than specifically a source code literal, use “0” or “zero” instead of “`0`”.)